# Why object.[[Prototype]] does not work in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to do call the `[[Prototype]]` method of an object, by using this tutorial, from Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), but it does not seem to work.

Does anyone knows why?

Thanks,

Some code:

```
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
}

Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v) {
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }
};

var g = new Graph();
g.[[Prototype]];
```

Comment: The tutorial clearly says: _the `[[Prototype]]` is accessed using the accessors `Object.getPrototypeOf()` and `Object.setPrototypeOf()`. This is equivalent to the JavaScript property `__proto__` which is non-standard but de-facto implemented by many browsers._

Comment: Because it's invalid syntax.

Comment: ... so to access the prototype use the `Object.getPrototypeOf(g)` or `g.__proto__` not `g.[[Prototype]]` which actually should throw an error.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/28916710/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/33075262/1048572

Answer (score 2):

Because you trying to access prototype wrong way, it should be `g.__proto__` (but you should never use `g.__proto__`, it's deprecated and does not work on all objects) or `Object.getPrototypeOf(g)`:

```js
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
}

Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v) {
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }
};

var g = new Graph();
console.log(g.__proto__); // get access to prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(g)); // get access to prototype
```

### UPDATE

*"I would like to execute something live new Graph(3), and expect the vertices to have 3 in the array."*

Just use `g.addVertex(3);` to invoke `addVertex` function with parameter `3` (it will change only `g.vertices` array). Here is the example:

```js
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
}

Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v) {
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }
};

var g = new Graph();
g.addVertex(3);
console.log(g.vertices);
```

But you can pass parameter to constructor as well, like this:

```js
function Graph(param) {
  this.vertices = [param];
  this.edges = [];
}

Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v) {
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }
};

var g = new Graph(1);
var h = new Graph(2);
console.log(g.vertices);
console.log(h.vertices);
```

Comment: You should never use `g.__proto__`. It's deprecated and does not work on all objects!

Comment: @Bergi, didn't know about that, thanks! I'll correct my answer

Comment: Thanks, @Commercial Suicide. How to call the function addVertex with some argument, exactly? Since it's a constructor, I would like to execute something live `new Graph(3)`, and expect the vertices to have 3 in the array. What is the syntax?