# Where are Map entries stored?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, es6-map

If I try to create a Map without calling the constructor, the object is unusable:

```js
const map = Object.create(Map.prototype);
map.entries();
```

Out of curiosity, I wondered where the entries were stored but the constructor does not seem to add properties:

```js
const map = new Map;
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(map) === Map.prototype);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(map));
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why does it really matter? It's going to be an implementation detail. This might not even be visible from within JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're stored in an [internal slot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33075262/1048572) of the object, which only gets created when you call `new Map`. It's an implementation detail of the native collections. You can only access entries through the native methods.