# Why does the TypeScript compiler compile its optional chaining and null-coalescing operators with two checks?

Tags: typescript, language-design

Why does the TypeScript compiler compile its [optional chaining and null-coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) operators, `?.` and `??`, to

```js
// x?.y
x === null || x === void 0 ? void 0 : x.y;

// x ?? y
x !== null && x !== void 0 ? x : y
```

instead of

```js
// x?.y
x == null ? void 0 : x.y

// x ?? y
x != null ? x : y
```

?

Odds are that behind the scenes `== null` does the same two checks, but even for the sake of code length, it seems like single check would be cleaner. It adds many fewer parentheses when using a string of optional chaining, too.

Incidentally, I'm also surprised that optional chaining doesn't compile to

```js
x == null ? x : x.y
```

to preserve `null` vs `undefined`.  This has since been answered: [Why does JavaScript's optional chaining to use undefined instead of preserving null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69856082/3120446)

Comment: Oh, I noticed "Incidentally, I'm also surprised that .."   The answer is that [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is not supposed to preserve `null`... it always produces `undefined` when the thing being referenced is nullish.  The reason I'm putting this in a comment and not my answer below is that this really is a separate question and [belongs in its own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366).

Comment: Yeah, I threw that on at the end after you posted your answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69856082/3120446

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can find an authoritative answer in [microsoft/TypeScript#16](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) (wow, an old one); it is specifically explained in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16#issuecomment-515694505):

> That's because of `document.all` [...], a quirk that gets special treatment in the language for backwards compatibility.
>
> ```
> document.all == null // true
> document.all === null || document.all === undefined // false
> ```
>
> In the optional chaining proposal
>
> ```
> document.all?.foo === document.all.foo
> ```
>
> but `document.all == null ? void 0 : document.all.foo` would incorrectly return `void 0`.

So there is a [particular](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-IsHTMLDDA-internal-slot) idiosyncratic deprecated obsolete wacky legacy [pseudo-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075262/what-is-an-internal-slot-of-an-object-in-javascript) edge case of type [`HTMLAllCollection`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#the-htmlallcollection-interface) that nobody uses, which is loosely equal to `null` but not strictly equal to either `undefined` or `null`.  Amazing!

It doesn't seem like anyone seriously considered just *breaking* things for `document.all`.  And since the `xxx === null || xxx === undefined` version works for all situations, it's probably the tersest way of emitting backward-compatible JS code that behaves according to the spec.

Comment: Good ol' JavaScript.  It's learning things like this that make me feel like JS is still as embarrassing as PHP.  I wonder if we'll ever get a `'use strict 20XX'` that does away with all the long-deprecated features.

Comment: "the main differences are that it allows a staggering variety of different (ab)uses of its methods" Whew, when you're saying that about *JavaScript*...

Comment: As an aside, in Babel there is a ["noDocumentAll" assumption](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/assumptions#nodocumentall) that you can enable to cause it to output the more terse version. I don't believe TS has an equivalent setting currently.

Comment: I don't get why `document.all === undefined` is used instead of the safer `typeof document.all === 'undefined'`... Can someone please explain?

Comment: @Rodolphe - what makes you think it is in any way less safe nowadays? The says of `undefined` being writable are long gone.

Comment: You're right about that. My first thought was about using `document.all === null || document.all === undefined`, which gives `false`, instead of `document.all === null || typeof document.all === 'undefined'`, which gives `true`, just like `document.all == null`. But I've surely missed a point.