# Why can't I create an empty Map or Set using Object.create?

Tags: javascript

The following doesn't work:

```js
const x = Object.create(Set.prototype)

x.has(1)
```

```js
const y = Object.create(Map.prototype)

y.get(1)
```

I was hoping for a type-independent way of creating empty objects.
Why doesn't the above work like that?

Comment: I suspect `Object.create()` doesn't call the class constructor.

Comment: Why not use `new type`?

Comment: like this? `function empty(x) { return new x.constructor }`? Brilliant

Comment: No, just `{ return new x; }`. I assume `x` is something like `Set` or `Map`.

Comment: The `x` argument would be an instance of what I want an empty instance for

Comment: Then I think what you wrote will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.create` creates a new ordinary object inheriting from the passed argument. It does nothing to initialise that object, like call the constructor.

In the case of `Set` and `Map`, calling the constructor essential, as that creates the [internal slots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33075262/1048572) which the collection needs to function (in particular, to store elements). These internal slots must be constructed together with the object, they cannot be added afterwards. This works only by calling the constructor with the `new` keyword.

When you use `Object.create`, the objects inherit `has` and `get` methods from the respective prototype object just fine, but when calling them their *receiver* (`this` value) is the ordinary object which is missing those internal slots that would make it a true `Set` or `Map`, and the methods throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it:

call `new ctor` where `ctor` is the object's contructor.