# How javascript function objects are created and get their internal properties

Tags: javascript

https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/the-anatomy-of-a-javascript-function#creating-function-instances_3

I am trying to understand this article on how javascript function objects are created.
It says:

`The new instance object is implicitly assigned many internal properties, one being the [[prototype]] property. The Function constructor’s prototype property referencing it’s prototype object is copied into this new object’s [[prototype]] property`

Basing on the above statement i wrote this code:

```
function Person(){

}

console.dir(Function.prototype);
console.dir(Person.prototype);
```

According to the statement Function.prototype is assigned to a newly created function object's prototpe (Person.prototype in this case). i printed both of them. Contents look different.

Can someone explain where my understanding went wrong. By the way i looked at Ecmascript specs as well, it has the same statement

[image]

Comment: According to javascript functions are objects. Even Ecmascript calls the same http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2

Comment: I want to know how each function get its internal properties and methods like prototype, call, bind etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing the classic confusion between the `prototype` property, and an object's prototype. They are entirely different, although related.

The `prototype` **property** of a function is an object which is set as the prototype for objects created using that function as a constructor. Initially, it is an empty object except for a `constructor` property pointing back to the constructor.

The **prototype** (not the `prototype` property) of an object is set when the object is created, from the `prototype` property of the constructor. It may be referred to as the `__proto__` property, or retrieved via `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

In your case, `Person` has a `prototype` **property** which is initially basically empty except for the `constructor` property. It has nothing to do with the `prototype` property of the `Function` object. It becomes the prototype of instances of `Person` created via `new Person()`. You can add your own methods and properties to it, as in `Person.prototype.alert = function() { alert(this.name); };`.

Entirely separately from its `prototype` **property**, `Person` has a prototype which comes from the `prototype` property of the `Function` object, since `Person` is implicitly created using the `Function` constructor. That's where `Person` gets `bind` etc. (although if you intend to use `Person` as a constructor, I doubt if you'd find much use for `bind`).

To get a better idea, try the following in your console:

```
function Person() { }
Person.__proto__ === Function.prototype  // true
Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Person) // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Person) === Function.prototype // true
```

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thanks for edits to make it more understandable

Answer (score 5):

> According to the statement, `Function.prototype` is assigned to a newly created function object's prototype (`Person.prototype` in this case)

No. The text talks about [**internal** properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11003021/1048572), such as [[prototype]]. You cannot access it as a normal property, you can access it using [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf). And indeed,

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Person) === Function.prototype // true
```

The `.prototype` property is a different thing. It does get created on instantiation of the function object as well, but it does get filled with an object that inherits from (has [[prototype]]) `Object.prototype` and contains a `.constructor` property pointing back to the function. This object will become the [[prototype]] of instances created using `new Person`.

Comment: "You cannot access it as a normal property". But We add properties to prototype? to make those properties available to all instances of that function

Comment: Yes, the properties *of* the object referenced by [[prototype]] can be accessed as normal, because they are inherited (which is what the whole thing is about), but the [[prototype]] link itself cannot be accessed using a property.