# Method's property [[HomeObject]] in Ecmascript 6

Tags: ecmascript-6

In ES6, method is now defined as a property that has an internal [[HomeObject]] property.  Is the syntax [[...]] denote an array of array? Why use this syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003021/what-internal-property-in-ecmascript-is-defined-for

Comment: FYI, this notation has been used for a long time.